# MySQL how to get if a user follows a post or not

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to Join two tables without any lack

```
+---------+
| users   |
+---------+
| userID  |
| name    |
+---------+

+---------+
| post    |
+---------+
| postID  |
| title   |
+---------+


+---------+
| follow  |
+---------+
| followID|
| userId  |
| postID  |
+---------+
```

I want to return all the posts and at the end add a column "Following" which will be 1 if the user follows the post (entry exists on follow table) or 0 if the user doesnt follow the post.

I think I have to use a Join here, but I am not sure how to achieve this.

Sample Data:

```
USER 
+--------+------+
| userid | NAME |
+--------+------+
|   1    | Mark |
|   2    | Jon  |
+--------+------+

Post
+--------+---------+
| postID |  title  |
+--------+---------+
|   1    | mypost  |
|   2    | mypost2 |
|   3    | mypost3 |
+--------+---------+

follow: 
+----------+--------+--------+
| followID | userId | postID |
+----------+--------+--------+
|    1     |   1    |   2    |
|    2     |   1    |   3    |
+----------+--------+--------+
```

The query GET postforuser/1

should return:

```
Post: 
+--------+---------+--------+
| postID | title   | follow |
+--------+---------+--------+
|   1    | mypost  |  NULL  |
|   2    | mypost2 |   1    |
|   3    | mypost3 |   2    |
+--------+---------+--------+
```

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: I added some sample data and what it should return. I hope this makes sense.